# How to write the type signature of a curried function in typescript

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

How do i write the type signature of a function like this in typescript?

```
var apply = (fn) => (list) => 
    fn.apply(null, list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var apply : (fn:Function) => (list:any[]) => any = (fn) => (list) => 
    fn.apply(null, list);
```

Another sample :

```
var foo = (a:number) => (b:number) => (c:number) => {
    return a + b + c; 
};

var add1 = foo(1);
var add2 = foo(1)(1);

console.log(add1(1)(1)); // 3 
console.log(add2(1)); // 3
```